# How to change a specific text in a merged cell and have it change the same text in other cells

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to be able to select a text within a merged cell and change it, such as the text `1st` to `2nd` and then run a macro that would be able to find the text `1st` in other merged cells and change it to `2nd`.

I'm not sure where to start. I've tried a replace statement, but that would require so much coding and complicated verbage.

This is what I have so far.

```
Dim rng As Range
rng = Range("A9:K10").Text
rng.Text = Replace(rng, "1st", "2nd")
End Sub
```

Comment: Did the answer bellow help you?

Answer (score 0):

This could help

```
Sub FindAndChangeText()
        Dim i As Range: Set i = Range("A1:Z100") 'Here you store a range with the text you need to change
        Dim Str01 As String: Str01 = "1st" 'This is the text you want to find inside the (i) range
        Dim Str02 As String: Str02 = "2nd" 'This is the new string you want instead
        Dim j As Range
        For Each j In i 'With this you goes through every cell in the range, no matter is merge or not. 
            If InStr(1, j.Value, Str01, 0) <> 0 Then ' if inside the cell exists the string you are looking for, the return something different to zero
                j.Replace Str01, Str02, xlPart 'xlPart = 2 review documentation for more info about range.replace and InStr(). Here you change the value inside your string
            End If
        Next j
End Sub
```

[**InStr Function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)

> Returns a Variant (Long) specifying the position of the first
>   occurrence of one string within another.
>
> ```
> Dim SearchString, SearchChar, MyPos
> SearchString ="XXpXXpXXPXXP"    ' String to search in.
> SearchChar = "P"    ' Search for "P".
>
> ' A textual comparison starting at position 4. Returns 6.
> MyPos = Instr(4, SearchString, SearchChar, 1)    
>
> ' A binary comparison starting at position 1. Returns 9.
> MyPos = Instr(1, SearchString, SearchChar, 0)
>
> ' Comparison is binary by default (last argument is omitted).
> MyPos = Instr(SearchString, SearchChar)    ' Returns 9.
>
> MyPos = Instr(1, SearchString, "W")    ' Returns 0.
> ```

[**Range.Replace method**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace)

> Returns a Boolean indicating characters in cells within the specified range. Using this method doesn't change either the selection or the active cell.
>
> ```
> Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Replace _ 
>  What:="SIN", Replacement:="COS", _ 
>  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
> ```

You can do something to bypass cells with empty values.

```
Sub FindAndChangeText()
        Dim i As Range: Set i = Range("A1:D10") 'Here you store a range with the text you need to change
        Dim Str01 As String: Str01 = "1st" 'This is the text you want to find inside the (i) range
        Dim Str02 As String: Str02 = "2nd" 'This is the new string you want instead
        Dim j As Range
        For Each j In i
            If Not j.Value = "" Then
                If InStr(1, j.Value, Str01, 0) <> 0 Then
                    j.Replace Str01, Str02, xlPart 'xlPart = 2
                End If
            End If
        Next j
End Sub
```

**Errors**

In your code:

```
    Dim rng As Range
    rng = Range("A1:K10").Text 'To store a Range type var, you need to use "Set"
                           'Set rng = youRange
                           'the whole object. Not just the .text or .value or .address
                           'those are components inside the object Range, with their own
                           'different type of value (string, int, double, etc)

    rng.Text = Replace(rng, "1st", "2nd")   'If you store the var in the right way
                                        'set rng = yourRange
                                        'You can not take the text inside the whole range.
                                        'Because you have several cells inside your range
                                        'with text in every cell
                                        'that is why you need to go for every cell in yourRange
                                        'Also REPLACE is a method for a cell inside a Range.
```